# Why is my flutter_animate transition not hapenning?

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-animation

So basically I have been trying to achieve an animation. Also using [flutter_animate 4.2.0+1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animate) package.
First let me show you the code:

in `auth_page.dart` file:

```
class AuthPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AuthPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<AuthPage> createState() => _AuthPageState();
}

class _AuthPageState extends State<AuthPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
         ...
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
           ////SEE HERE////
              AuthBox().animate(target: authBoxTarget ? 1 : 0).slideY(
                    delay: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                    begin: 0,
                    end: 1,
                  ),
             ///////////
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

In the `authbox.dart` file for the button: the `onTap` function:

```
      onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      authBoxTarget = true;
    });
    Future.delayed(
      Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      () {
        showGeneralDialog(
                 ...
            transitionBuilder: ... );
            return SlideTransition(
              position: tween.animate(...),
              child: child,
            );
          },
          pageBuilder: (context, _, __) {
            return Center(
              child: Container(...
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Login',
                    style: TextStyle(...),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ).then((_) {
          setState(() {
            authBoxTarget = false;
          });
        });
      },
    );
  },
```

This should work right?
-when the dialogue appears the authbox should slide down and on dismissed the authbox should come back up.
But this is not hapenning the dialogue is coming but authbox is not going down...why??? give me solution.

`mail.dart` file:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
  Animate.restartOnHotReload = true;
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: const AuthPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you refine your question by formatting and `AuthBox` is missing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after a lot of research this is finally how to do it.

`authbox.dart`:

```
class AuthBox extends StatefulWidget {

  final void Function(bool) callback; //add this line here
  const AuthBox({super.key, required this.callback}); //update this line
.
.
.

class _AuthBoxState extends State<AuthBox> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ... (
.
.
.

onTap: (){ //inside onTap function

  widget.callback(true); //add this line

  Future.delayed(
    Duration (milliseconds: 100)

    showGeneratDiatog(...

          //at the end of showGeneratDiatog add the following then function
     ...).then((_) {
            widget.callback(false);
          });
```

`auth_page.dart`:

```
class _AuthPageState extends State<AuthPage> {

  bool authBoxTarget = false; //add the following boolean 

  //define the following function
  void triggerAuthBoxAnimation(bool showAuthBox) {
    setState(() {
      authBoxTarget = showAuthBox;
    });
  }
.
.
.   

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(...
    ... AuthBox(
                callback: triggerAuthBoxAnimation, //add the required callback function
              )
                  .animate(target: authBoxTarget ? 1 : 0) //add the target to animate
                  .slideY(
                      delay: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                      begin: 0,
                      end: 1,
                  )
```

That's it. Now it should work as desired. When the button in `authbox` is clicked it will notify in `authpage` through the `void Function(bool) callback;` and it will change the authBoxTarget value to true through the `void triggerAuthBoxAnimation function` and thus `target` value will be `1` and both the animation will take place together.

Answer (score 2):

Add a callback to `AuthBox` to toggle the animation state:

```
AuthBox(onDismiss: () => setState(() => authBoxTarget = !authBoxTarget))
```

Receive the callback in `AuthBox`:

```
class AuthBox extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onDismiss;
  ...
}
```

Use `WillPopScope` in the dialog to handle dismisses(and remove your .then() on the dialog):

```
onPressed: () async {
            onDismiss();
            await Future.delayed(
              const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              () => showGeneralDialog(
                context: context,
                pageBuilder: (BuildContext buildContext, Animation animation, Animation secondaryAnimation) {
                  return WillPopScope(
                    onWillPop: () async {
                      onDismiss();
                      return true;
                    },
                    child: /*your dialog content */
)}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run both animations at once, you can declare a new bool in your code, for example:

```
bool isButtonPressed=false;
```

Then, in your onTap handler, you add this at the beginning:

```
setState(() {
              isButtonPressed = true;
            });
```

After your showGeneralDialog you add this:

```
.then((value) {
                  setState(() {
                    isButtonPressed = false;
                  });
                })
```

And this is the code for your Animate Widget with the authbox inside:

```
isButtonPressed
          ? Animate(
              effects: [
                SlideEffect(
                  end: Offset(0, 1),
                  delay: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                  curve: Curves.ease,
                ),
              ],
              child: authbox(),
            )
          : authbox()
```

Simple solution, but it works.
If you have any more questions, you can ask them in the comments.

Comment: Not working dude. i did as you said, even after the value changed the animation of the authbox is not havening

Comment: Is your onTap Function and the animation of the authbox in the same stateful widget? If not, put them in the same statful widget and it should work. If you don't want it to be in the same stateful widget, you can make some void callbacks from your function. If you don't know how this works, let me know, then I will help you with it.

Comment: It will be helpful if you show me, how to use that void function in my case.